# Cannot be resolved to a type: Error

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am getting this error: ShowDialog cannot be resolved to a type

Here is my code:

```
final CharSequence[] items = {"Low", "Medium", "High"};

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowDialog.this);
builder.setTitle("Alert Dialog with ListView");
builder.setIcon(R.drawable.image1);
builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

alert.show();
```

Any ideas why I am getting this annoying error? I have tried to refresh my code and also clean it and still no luck. Thanks

Comment: What is your class name? or put the code of whole class

Comment: It would be also helpful if you add a part of traceback.

Comment: What class? This is a code to show a AlertDialog. I simply imported this: import android.app.AlertDialog; I dont know why I am getting it or how to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ShowDialog` was most likely the class name you got the `AlertDialog` example from.

To make it work, you can replace `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ShowDialog.this);` with `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);` if `this` is of Activity type or `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(<your_activity_class_name>.this);` otherwise.

Note that if you are trying to show the dialog from within an event handler (usually inside an anonymous class), you have to go for the second option, `AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(<your_activity_class_name>.this);`.

To understand the changes better: the [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder%28android.content.Context%29) you're getting the error on is accepting a `Context` as argument, hence the need to provide either `this` or `<your_activity_class_name>.this` to it as context of the Activity you're executing from.

Comment: Thank you! I was so dumb. I had to just put the name of my activity in there such as MainActivity in my case. Thats the problem of using example code :( I am new to this type of development and thats why. Thanks again! Saved mu life!